# Get value from input with onclick

Tags: javascript

How can I get the value of input on click using vanilla javascript?

```js
function getvalue() {
  console.log(this.val);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onclick="getvalue()" value="asdf"></input>
<input type="text" onclick="getvalue()" value="asdf2"></input>
<input type="text" onclick="getvalue()" value="asdf3"></input>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use event.target.value inside your function call

When function gets called `event` object is passed to the function. `event.target` identifies which element called the function.

```js
function getvalue() {
   console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onclick="getvalue()" value="asdf"></input>
<input type="text" onclick="getvalue()" value="asdf2"></input>
<input type="text" onclick="getvalue()" value="asdf3"></input>
```

Comment: This is now deprecated

Answer (score 5):

```js
function getvalue(t) {
   console.log(t.value);
}
```

```html
<input onclick="getvalue(this)" value="asdf"></input>
<input onclick="getvalue(this)" value="asdf2"></input>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using vanilla javascript, you can do that like this:

```js
function getValue(o) {
  console.log(o.value);
}
```

```html
<input value="asdf" onclick="getValue(this)"></input>
<input value="asdf2" onclick="getValue(this)"></input>
<input value="asdf3" onclick="getValue(this)"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass element's reference to function `getValue( this )`
and then  use as  `function getValue( self ){ /*self.stuff*/ }`
or
You can also do it by adding click listener.

```js
window.onload = function(){
const elms = document.getElementsByClassName('element');
   
  for(let i = 0; i < elms.length; i++){ 
    elms[i].addEventListener( 'click', function(){
        console.log( this.value );
     })
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input class="element" value="asdf" />
<input class="element" value="asdf2" />
<input class="element" value="asdf3" />
```