# <div> innerHTML Hiding after display

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML tag  problem, i loop a div content and trying to display,but after i display it`enter code here` hides. I was wondering what is my mistakes or needs to display properly

```js
let track;

track =
  '[ {"status":"Initialize","date":"2022-04-24"}, {"status":"Process","date":"2022-04-25"}, {"status":"Completed","date":"2022-04-27"} ]';

function DisplayTrack() {
  populateTrack(track);
}

function populateTrack() {
  var container = document.querySelector("#track_detail");
  var data = JSON.parse(track);

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i + 1 == data.length) {
      container.innerHTML +=
        '<div class="node_active"><h3>' +
        data[i].status +
        "</h3><p>" +
        data[i].date +
        "</p></div>";
    } else {
      container.innerHTML +=
        '<div class="node_done"><h3>' +
        data[i].status +
        "</h3><p>" +
        data[i].date +
        "</p></div>";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="trackBox">
  <h1>Search</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Type.." id="txt_search">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Search" id="btn_search" onclick="DisplayTrack()">
  </form>

  <div id="listItem">
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
      <div class="description"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="track_progress" id="track_detail">
</div>
```

It display the loop content but it hides after the display

Comment: You have a <form> there, and since you're submitting it without stating `method` or `action`, these default to GET and the current URL, which is the equivalent of reloading the page. Just remove the form tags, you're using inline code to handle the click anyway.

Comment: I see! thanks man, basically I was doing a step progress bar, I was using the form search  Searching the ID, and call api with json return and display the content.

Comment: This question is marked as `[duplicate]`. Other than the above one, you may also consider to find answer from this post: [Get value from input with onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177516/10100812)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `type submit` to the input, so when you search it submits the form and reloads the page, you need to prevent the standard behaviour if you want the page not to refresh:

```
const form = document.querySelector("form")
form.onsubmit = e => e.preventDefault()
```

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form")
form.onsubmit = e => e.preventDefault()


let track;

track =
  '[ {"status":"Initialize","date":"2022-04-24"}, {"status":"Process","date":"2022-04-25"}, {"status":"Completed","date":"2022-04-27"} ]';

function DisplayTrack() {
  populateTrack(track);
}

function populateTrack() {
  var container = document.querySelector("#track_detail");
  var data = JSON.parse(track);

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i + 1 == data.length) {
      container.innerHTML +=
        '<div class="node_active"><h3>' +
        data[i].status +
        "</h3><p>" +
        data[i].date +
        "</p></div>";
    } else {
      container.innerHTML +=
        '<div class="node_done"><h3>' +
        data[i].status +
        "</h3><p>" +
        data[i].date +
        "</p></div>";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="trackBox">
  <h1>Search</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Type.." id="txt_search">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Search" id="btn_search" onclick="DisplayTrack()">
  </form>

  <div id="listItem">
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
      <div class="description"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="track_progress" id="track_detail">
</div>
```

Comment: They shouldn't use a submit button in the first place, rather than denying the default behaviour.

Comment: Why not, he might want to perform an ajax while displaying the results, it's a common pattern to use a `submit` event listener on a form, to perform an ajax with the form data retrieved directy from the submit event target .

Answer (score 1):

Just change input button type to `button` instead of `submit` because type of submit will trigger page reload.

```
<input type="button" name="" value="Search" id="btn_search" onclick="DisplayTrack()">
```

Comment: If the answer is easy and obvious to you, it's a dupe. Search for the dupe and mark the question accordingly in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the content disappear because the form is getting submitted. By default, if you do not provide any ''action'' property to your html form, the page will be refreshed on submit.

To cancel the form submit, you can try this :

```html
<form id="my-form">
  ...
</form>
```

```js
document.getElementById("my-form").onsubmit = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
}
```